# set server errors for a reactive parent form control

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form in which I am setting the server error to the form controls. The code was working fine, but when I am passing this form as parent form to the another dynamic form group, I'm not able to set the errors.

I am getting field, message and error code from the server. whenever there is any error from the server, set the error to particular form control for which error is coming and showing the message on the UI

```
// setting parent form
this.dynamicForm.setParent(this.parentForm);

// setting errors

this.addEmployeeForm.controls[errorField].setErrors({ serverError: true});
```

Whenever there is any error coming from server, error should set to form control

Comment: can you please show some more piece of code here.

Comment: <dynamic-form-fields  *ngIf="dynamicFields.length > 0" [customFields]="dynamicFields" [parentForm]="addEmployeeForm" [isEdit] = "true">
                  
</kite-dynamic-form-fields>

Comment: doen't make any sense here create git repo and provide here link if possoiblE